# Created instance in an extension method is null

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I've created this extension method

```
public static void AddIfNullCreate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
 {
     if (dictionary == null)
     {
         dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
     }

     dictionary.Add(key, value);
 }
```

But when I use it

```
    public void DictionaryTest()
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> d = GetD();

        d.AddIfNullCreate(1,"ss");
    }

    private IDictionary<int, string> GetD()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

After calling AddIfNullCreate is d null. Why is that so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like any other method, a change to the *parameter* doesn't change the caller's *argument* unless it's a `ref` parameter (which it can't be for an extension method first parameter). [The argument is passed by value](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html), even if that value is a reference.

One option is to return the dictionary too:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> AddIfNullCreate<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    dictionary.Add(key, value);
    return dictionary;
}
```

Then:

```
d = d.AddIfNullCreate(1, "ss");
```

However, I'm not sure I'd really do that. I think I'd just conditionally create the dictionary in the method itself:

```
public void DictionaryTest()
{
    IDictionary<int, string> d = GetD() ?? new Dictionary<int, string>();

    d[1] = "ss";
}
```

Comment: Jon is here, nothing to add, as always :) +1

Answer (score 3):

If this was done as a normal method you'd need to pass the dictionary as a ref parameter so that the memory pointer to the newly created object is set correctly.  I don't think you'll be allowed to specify the first parameter of an extension method as a ref parameter though.